# Magnific popup and Woo add to cart variation

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, magnific-popup

I am using magnific popup to show images, and in that popup are variations you can choose before adding the image to the cart in the popup.

Here is the callback part of the magnific js. In it I am calling to the Woo add to cart variation js file. I have to call this js file each time an image is loaded so it will display the woo variations properly. Loading that file one time on the page does not work for the popup.

```
type: "image",
            callbacks: {
                imageLoadComplete: function() {

                    jQuery.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js");

                },
             } .... etc
```

So each time you click to see the next photo the add-to-cart-variation.min.js is loaded. Sometimes it takes a moment for that file to completely load because it has a bunch of other calls to run other php functions. If you click the next arrow a bunch of times real fast to see other photos is where the problem starts because the getScript file is getting loaded each time you click next, and after a while it freezes everything up.

Even if I add woo js in the imageLoadComplete area instead of using the getScript I still have this problem, so it's not getScript causing the issue it's the additional functions that are run after the js is loaded.  Using a setimeout is not an option either because it will still run no matter what.

How can I stop this problem from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Works on mobile too, at least on ios.

So I add the class disabled to the button so give it that disabled look in color. Then when you hover over the div that contains the variations I load the woo script, then I remove the class over the hover div so no more hover actions can happen including the woo script. Works great on chrome, safari and firefox on mac os and safari on mobile ios.

```
type: "image",
     callbacks: {
        imageLoadComplete: function() {

         if(jQuery('.ft-gallery-variations-text').hasClass('ft-gallery-js-load')) {
            jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('disabled');
           }

         jQuery( ".ft-gallery-js-load" ).hover(function() {
            if(jQuery('.ft-gallery-variations-text').hasClass('ft-gallery-js-load')){
               jQuery.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js");
               jQuery('.ft-gallery-variations-text').removeClass('ft-gallery-js-load');
              }
         });

      },
   } .... etc
```